# how to set a range to be a variable column and delete entire row if criteria is met vba

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization

i have a counter that will identify a specific column based on the header name.
that counter is the variable "k" and k=5

now in my code i need it to reference that column as my range so that i can delete that entire row where a certain criteria is met

i have 2 issues:
1. my range is not being set. I don't want to hardcode the range column
2. my loop is not running

```
Dim physicalstr As String
physicalstr = "Physical"
Dim physrange As Range
Set physrange = ShtTwo.Columns(k)

For Each cell In physrange
    If ActiveCell.Value = physicalstr _
    Then ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problems with your code are that `activecell` is never assigned, never changes and is not referenced in your loop (which involves `cell`). You don't need to [activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) anyway.

When deleting rows or columns you must loop backwards to avoid skipping rows. To loop backwards it's easier to use a counter variable for your loop rather than a range.

Also, do you really need to go through all million rows? Consider using `Find` or `Autofilter` for more efficient code.

```
Dim physicalstr As String
physicalstr = "Physical"
Dim physrange As Range
Set physrange = ShtTwo.Columns(k)
Dim r As Long

For r = physrange.Count To 1 Step -1
    If physrange.Cells(r).Value = physicalstr Then physrange.Cells(r).EntireRow.Delete
Next r
```